# Numerical stability issue in Pandas rolling correlation calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I came across a strange behavior of Pandas rolling correlation. In the code snippet below, I'd assume `v1 == v2` is true but it turns out not. This causes inf in rolling correlation (c1 vs. c2, where c2 is fine but c1 is "wrong" in my opinion):

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([1e5, 0, 0, 0, 0])
b = pd.Series([9.45] * 5)
c1 = a.rolling(5).corr(b).iloc[4]
c2 = a.corr(b)
v1 = a.rolling(5).cov(b).iloc[4]
v2 = a.cov(b)
```

I tested it in multiple machines and `abs(v1)` is O(1e-11), `v2` is 0, and `c` is inf. Is this a known issue or not? And why is rolling cov different from vanilla cov?

Answer (score 1):

Covariance is not just a number. It is a measure. Its value is pretty hard to interpret. Given the value only it's even harder. That's why correlation is usually used instead of covariance (as upgraded version of it). Values `0` and `1e-11` differ but have the same meaning - samples seem to have no linear relation.

As for calculation `pandas.Series.cov(pandas.Series)` and `pandas.Series.rolling(..., ddof=...).cov(pandas.Series)` use (slightly?) different algorithms: [numpy cov](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.4/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2121-L2327) and [rolling cov](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/window.py#L2207-L2224) (actually [ewmcov](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/window.pyx#L1802)) respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the difference between cov and corr. What concerns me here is the numerical issue w.r.t. rolling corr (I guess it's probably something like ewmcorr?). Since the standard deviation of a constant sequence is 0, the correlation between it and any other sequence would be a 0/0. Returning nan as what the vanilla corr does is fine, but returning inf is annoying and misleading.